# Convert Word Table -> "Something" -> LaTeX

Tags: tables, msword

It's seems that it's not easy to convert Word table to LaTeX (especially when it contains some enumerations inside etc.). I'm wondering if it's possible to export Word table to some code which would be easy enough to analyze (i.e. to find out where the cell starts, whether it contains enumeration etc.) and then based on this code create some function (for example in Python) which would create the appropriate LaTeX code. Is it possible or maybe there already exists some interesting tools to convert complicated Word tables into LaTeX?

**EDIT** I would like to create (or find) free version of this tool: https://www.docx2latex.com/

Comment: I'm sure it's possible but probably not easy. However, the real question is: Why would you want to do that? Why not just create the table directly in LaTeX (or export it directly from wherever the data is generated, if applicable)? Making a Word table first seems like introducing complication for no reason.

Comment: I suggest trying Writer2LaTeX (an extension for LibreOffice): it supports tables. (And, of course, LibreOffice can open docx files)

Comment: Unrelated: VBA for Word has access to Word's document-object model, and can iterate through cells, rows, columns, paragraphs, words, characters, etc etc. If you record a macro of, say, creating and populating a table, then look at the resulting VBA code, it will have the object names and actions.

Comment: Then, for example, you can edit the code to generalize the actions, write an output file, wrapping the output with LaTeX commands, and so on. Alternatively, scan from the other direction: .docm, .docx files are (zipped) XML, so readable text. But sometimes it's faster to just copy-and-paste (into Excel (or LibreOffice spreadsheet), for example, and use concatenate and substitute formulas to build latex-code on a production-line basis, and so ending up with a two-step process).